# Json format with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

```
    var alarmModels  = AlarmModel.GetAlarms(siteId,subSiteIds,departIds);
    var items = new List<dynamic>();
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var model in alarmModels)
    {
        dynamic item = new {label = model.Name, data = new {model.Unack,i}};
        items.Add(item);
        i++;
    }

    return items;
```

I have above code in my mvc model which is later parsed into json in controller.

```
return Json(item);
```

In my developer console i can see the data returned is  has

```
Object(label:"CheckList" data = Object(uncak :1,i:2))
```

I am poting the data with help of jquery plot plugin as table.

Which accepts data in this format.

```
Object(label:"CheckList" data = Object(1,2))
```

I tried

```
dynamic item = new {label = model.Name, data = new int[]{model.Unack,i}};
```

But this returns.

```
Object(label:"CheckList" data = Object(0 :1,1:2))
```

Comment: so?..................

Comment: Yet that is the format that it returns.

Comment: Are you asking how you can specify that `data` should should be an array?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var alarmModels  = AlarmModel.GetAlarms(siteId,subSiteIds,departIds);
    var items = new List<dynamic>();
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var model in alarmModels)
    {
        dynamic item = new { label = model.Name, data = new[] { new[] { i, model.Unack } }};
        items.Add(item);
        i++;
    }        
    return items;
```

Above fixed my problem.